# switch.isChecked always false

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using switch component inside  my list item. But no matter I enable the switch or not. It's returning false.

```
  group_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (group_select.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Checked at "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (!group_select.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Unchecked at "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        });
```

Thanx for the help....

Comment: It would help if you said what class group_select is an instance of.

Comment: @Doge post your full code

Comment: wait! It should work unless you recreate the view again are you using setContentView again?

Comment: I changed it to setOnCheckedChangeListener and it worked @Charuka Thanx :)

Comment: @Doge as you wish but you didn't understood the real problem setOnClickListener works too unless you make a mistake anyways good luck

Comment: I am using setOnclickListener in the getView method of adapter @Charuka .

Comment: `if (c) {...} else if (!c) {...}` is logically equivalent to `if (c) {...} else {...}` modulo side effects of `c`. If there were side effects then the first idiom is an invitation to bugs. `group_select` doesn't follow the naming conventions.

Comment: I know I made else if to check that if it's showing the check value false or there is any different reason..After that I changed again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton); 
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        } });
```

Comment: Thanx for the help.. I will accept it as answer in 2 mins

Answer (score 2):

```
mSubscriptionSw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // checked
                } else {
                    // not checked
                }
            }
        });
```